# Using 'each' to print chunks of an array

Tags: ruby

Working through Day 2 of Ruby in "7 Languages in 7 Weeks" - the answer to the second question seems acceptable, the first one feels quite wrong. Any suggestions?

1. Print the contents of an array of sixteen numbers, four numbers at a
   time, using just `each`.

   ```
   group = 0

   (1..16).each do |x| 
       print x
       group = group + 1
       if group % 4 == 0
           puts
           group = 0
       end
   end
   ```
2. Now, do the same with `each_slice` in `Enumerable` (copied directly from http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

   ```
   (1..16).each_slice(4) {|x| p x}
   ```

Comment: (1..16) is not an array. Besides using `each`, the first solution uses  `print and puts` from the Kernel class, and `% and +`from Numeric. This book is not for me.

Comment: steenslag: Those are just my *attempts* at answers :) Could you clarify your point a bit more perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to save `group` `x` already saving it.

```
(1..16).each do |x|
  print x
  puts if x % 4 == 0
end
```

Comment: Oh geez. *facepalm*

Comment: ruby style block arguments is coming strange to other language users.

Comment: That is not a right answer, try with array of random number...